# How I can evaluate an expression which contains the `Pi` constant using ICompiledBinding?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using the `ICompiledBinding` interface to evaluate simple expressions, If I use literals like `(2*5)+10` works fine , but when i try to compile something like `2*Pi` the code fails with the error :

> EEvaluatorError:Couldn't find Pi

This is my current code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Rtti,
  System.Bindings.EvalProtocol,
  System.Bindings.EvalSys,
  System.Bindings.Evaluator,
  System.SysUtils;


procedure Test;
Var
  RootScope : IScope;
  CompiledExpr : ICompiledBinding;
  R : TValue;
begin
  RootScope:= BasicOperators;
  //Compile('(2*5)+10', RootScope); //works
  CompiledExpr:= Compile('2*Pi', RootScope);//fails
  R:=CompiledExpr.Evaluate(RootScope, nil, nil).GetValue;
  if not R.IsEmpty then
   Writeln(R.ToString);
end;

begin
 try
    Test;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

So how I can evaluate an expression which contains the `Pi` constant using the ICompiledBinding interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far i know exists two options

1) You can initializate the [`IScope`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Bindings.EvalProtocol.IScope) interface using the `TNestedScope` class passing the `BasicOperators` and `BasicConstants` scopes.

**(The BasicConstants Scope define nil, true, False, and Pi.)**

```
Var
  RootScope : IScope;
  CompiledExpr : ICompiledBinding;
  R : TValue;
begin
  RootScope:= TNestedScope.Create(BasicOperators, BasicConstants);
  CompiledExpr:= Compile('2*Pi', RootScope);
  R:=CompiledExpr.Evaluate(RootScope, nil, nil).GetValue;
  if not R.IsEmpty then
  Writeln(R.ToString);
end;
```

2) you can add the Pi Value manually to the Scope using a sentence like this.

```
TDictionaryScope(RootScope).Map.Add('Pi', TValueWrapper.Create(pi));
```

and the code will look like this

```
Var
  RootScope : IScope;
  CompiledExpr : ICompiledBinding;
  R : TValue;
begin
  RootScope:= BasicOperators;
  TDictionaryScope(RootScope).Map.Add('Pi', TValueWrapper.Create(pi));
  CompiledExpr:= Compile('2*Pi', RootScope);
  R:=CompiledExpr.Evaluate(RootScope, nil, nil).GetValue;
  if not R.IsEmpty then
  Writeln(R.ToString);
end;
```